# After using a Summon that ends the fight, does the party member still increase their elemental power?

Tags: golden-sun

Usually when you use a summon that doesn't finish everyone off, it raises that party members elemental power. Does that still happen, even though the message isn't displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The fight ends, so, there's no need to increase the character's elemental power. Have in mind that this elemental power boost is in effect only during the fight, so, when the fight is over this boost is lost.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man. Exactly the info I was looking for.